Smallest power supply for STM32F103?
I'm using the STM32F103C (LQFP48 package) with a custom keyboard PCB running QMK, powered by the AMS1117-3.3, and it works very well.
I measured current consumption using something like this which I don't have handy anymore but it was around 20-50 milliamps IIRC.
So I'm trying the 200mA XC6206P332MR-G instead of the 1 amp AMS1117-3.3 and the current measurement was 0.000 amps but the test LED did turn on, so it must've been nonzero.
Now I've flashed the STM32duino bootloader into the STM32F103C but my computer isn't recognizing the keyboard via USB (lsusb doesn't show it at all).
So I'm wondering if the XC6206P332MR-G isn't a replacement for the AMS1117-3.3 (and, if not, what is? ideally in the SOT-23 package), or if there's something else going on.

Should be. Impossible to know without showing the schematic and how you wired the test. The AMS1117 and the XC6206 doesn't seem to be drop in replaceable so either you need to show your two sets of schem/layout or you need to show the board and the mod

there could be brief current pulses too quick to be measured by a slow digital meter and too large for the new LDO to stably supply.

They look to be equivalent to me, for currents within the electrical and thermal limits of the SOT23 package. Better, in fact, because the XC6206P332 is ceramic-capacitor compatible and the AMS1117 is not guaranteed to be.
If you measure the voltage at your MCU power pins with an oscilloscope (preferably) and it's a reasonably stable 3.3V then that's all the regulator can do.
However, if you choose not to hew to the input and output capacitor recommendations, it's quite possible you'll get a nifty oscillator that won't work too well as a keyboard. That does not preclude the LED appearing to be illuminated continuously. Capacitors of approximately the correct value and characteristics (ESR in particular) are non-optional for LDO regulators, in general.
